# message queue vs TCP IP Socket. which IPC is faster in linux?

Tags: ipc

I would like to know which IPC gives more performance in linux (TCP IP socket vs message queue). My purpose is to send data packets containing few integer values in frequent intervals (around 50 ms) from process A to B. B sends some other packets to A in 5 seconds intervals.

Comment: The message queue is never going to be slower, possibly faster.

Comment: You might also consider unix domain sockets. See [unix domain sockets vs posix mqueues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774346/which-is-better-for-local-ipc-posix-message-queues-mqueues-or-unix-domain-lo?rq=1)

Comment: You could have googled it 1st though

Answer (score 16):

Best results you'll get with **Shared Memory** solution.

**Message Queue** is 3 times better than **TCP sockets**.

Results are get with [IPC benchmarking](https://github.com/goldsborough/ipc-bench):

- System: Linux (Linux ubuntu 4.4.0 x86_64 i7-6700K 4.00GHz)
- Message: 128 bytes
- Messages count: 1000000

**Pipe benchmark:**

```
Message size:       128
Message count:      1000000
Total duration:     27367.454 ms
Average duration:   27.319 us
Minimum duration:   5.888 us
Maximum duration:   15763.712 us
Standard deviation: 26.664 us
Message rate:       36539 msg/s
```

**FIFOs (named pipes) benchmark:**

```
Message size:       128
Message count:      1000000
Total duration:     38100.093 ms
Average duration:   38.025 us
Minimum duration:   6.656 us
Maximum duration:   27415.040 us
Standard deviation: 91.614 us
Message rate:       26246 msg/s
```

**Message Queue benchmark:**

```
Message size:       128
Message count:      1000000
Total duration:     14723.159 ms
Average duration:   14.675 us
Minimum duration:   3.840 us
Maximum duration:   17437.184 us
Standard deviation: 53.615 us
Message rate:       67920 msg/s
```

**Shared Memory benchmark:**

```
Message size:       128
Message count:      1000000
Total duration:     261.650 ms
Average duration:   0.238 us
Minimum duration:   0.000 us
Maximum duration:   10092.032 us
Standard deviation: 22.095 us
Message rate:       3821893 msg/s
```

**TCP sockets benchmark:**

```
Message size:       128
Message count:      1000000
Total duration:     44477.257 ms
Average duration:   44.391 us
Minimum duration:   11.520 us
Maximum duration:   15863.296 us
Standard deviation: 44.905 us
Message rate:       22483 msg/s
```

**Unix domain sockets benchmark:**

```
Message size:       128
Message count:      1000000
Total duration:     24579.846 ms
Average duration:   24.531 us
Minimum duration:   2.560 us
Maximum duration:   15932.928 us
Standard deviation: 37.854 us
Message rate:       40683 msg/s
```

**ZeroMQ benchmark:**

```
Message size:       128
Message count:      1000000
Total duration:     64872.327 ms
Average duration:   64.808 us
Minimum duration:   23.552 us
Maximum duration:   16443.392 us
Standard deviation: 133.483 us
Message rate:       15414 msg/s
```

Comment: The Shared Memory benchmark (I assume it's [this](https://github.com/goldsborough/ipc-bench/blob/master/source/shm/server.c#L29)) performs busy-wait...